# How to get data from PHP array? Is currency symbol allowed in array key?

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

In case when PRICE IS SET in Product addons plugin the print_r outputs Array ( [129] => Array ( ...other values...[**Select Massage (190,00 €)**] => Relaxation 2h ) ), but in case when PRICE FIELD IS LEFT EMPTY print_r outputs Array ( [129] => Array ( ...other values...[**Select Massage**] => Relaxation 2h ) )

**In case price is in the key I cannot get the value out of array** (output is an empty string), whereas if there is no price in key the following code works normaly and outputs Relaxation 2h. Price is set in backend in Woocommerce Product addons plugin.

```
foreach ( $podatki as $item ) {
    $massage = $item['Select Massage'];         
}       
echo $massage;

RESULT: Relaxation 2h

foreach ( $podatki as $item ) {
    $massage = $item['Select Massage (190,00 €)'];          
}       
echo $massage;

RESULT: 'empty string'
```

Since the price in Array key is changing according to customer selection I also wonder how to get data from array by checking only 'Select Massage' string part of the key?

Comment: No idea what you try to do here. Also if the price changes you probably want to use it as value and not as key in your array.

Comment: I am not using it in array myself. This is the array that gets constructed by woocommerce. I just want to retrive data from it.

Comment: Then show us the array structure with: `print_r($podatki);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default function that would let you select items from an array using partial keys. But you can do it by manually iterating over the array:

```
foreach ($podatki as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'Select Massage') === 0) {
            $massage = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will set `$massage` to the value under the first key starting with `Select Massage` in the array.

Another approach would be to extract all values with keys starting with `Select Massage` into a separate array. This could be done like so:

```
$massages = array_filter(array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    return strpos($key, 'Select Massage') === 0 ? $value : null;
}, array_keys($item), $item));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: First solution works perfectly and solves everything I have written in my question. I did not test the second one though. Thank you very much Kuba.